# VBoxManage: Error: Can't be used as the requested device

Tags: virtualbox, hard-disk, virtual-machine, lvm, dd

I used the soluton from [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16299/using-a-lvm-partition-as-a-virtualbox-drive) but always i get

```
VirtualBox error: The medium 'lvol.vmdk' can't be used as the requested device type (0x80004005)
```

I've tried all controllers SATA, SCSI, IDE and SAS still not working.

Host SO: Ubuntu 12.04.1 amd64
VirtualBox 4.1

lvol.vmdk was create with

```
vboxmanage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename /VDK/lvlol.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/vg/lv
```

the raw disk have:

```
1 primary ext3 156MB
2 primary swap 2147MB
3 primary ext3 4137MB
```

Comment: What does the `vmdk` file contain? (it should be a short text file). Is the LV device readable and writable (is it not in use by something else, like already mounted?). What has `dd` to do with all this?

Comment: What is the output for `id` and what is the ownership/permissions of the logical volume you created? What is the contents of `lvol.vmdk`? Please add this info to your question. What Operating System and which version do you use?

Comment: What does `cat /VDK/lvlol.vmdk` output?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a system comparable with Ubuntu 12.10, using udev, then you have to instruct udev to assign proper permissions to the logical volume you want to assign to Virtualbox.

To check current permissions to on the logical volume:

```
$ ls -lL /dev/mapper/vg_usbraid-vm_webserver
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      252,   8 Oct 26 09:26 vg-lv
id
uid=1000(username) gid=1000(groupid) groups=1000(groupid),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),46(plugdev),115(lpadmin),117(admin),122(sambashare)
```

And check if the group id of the device is listed in the group list from the `id` command.

The problem in the example above is that neither 'root' nor 'disk' is in the list that `id` spits out. Although it is easy to extend the group list for a user, this is really not what you want as adding either `root` or `disk` to your user account is a **major** security risk. You would be able as a normal user to write to *any* disk at a very low level. A better solution is explained below.

With the limited information available at the moment of writing, I cannot go into much detail, but this is what I've done to accomplish a Vbox VM running from a Logical Volume under my own username:

Create the following file: `/etc/udev/rules.d/65-vmdmsetup.rules`
with contents:

```
SUBSYSTEM!="block",                             GOTO="vm_device_mapper_end"
KERNEL!="dm-*",                                 GOTO="vm_device_mapper_end"
ACTION!="add|change",                           GOTO="vm_device_mapper_end"

# Obtain device status
IMPORT{program}="/sbin/dmsetup export -j%M -m%m"
ENV{DM_NAME}!="?*",                             GOTO="vm_device_mapper_end"

ENV{DM_NAME}=="vg_usbraid-vm_webserver",        GROUP="groupid"                                                

LABEL="vm_device_mapper_end"
```

Where:

- `vg_usbraid` is the name of the volume group
- `vm_webserver` is the name of the logical volume
- `groupid` is the group id that comes with your username. Check for 'gid=' in the output of `id`

Of course you need to reload udev, but making typos in udev rules can crash your system. So be sure to have closed as many applications as possible and maybe just run a `sync` to flush as much data to disk as possible. Consider increasing the log level so in case it doesn't work, at least you have some lead to what went wrong.

```
$ udevadm control --log-priority=info
$ sudo udevadm control --reload
```

On Ubuntu logging is redirected to `/var/log/syslog`.

Only once udev is set up, you should create the logical volume, otherwise udev will not see the events. If your LV already exists run a:

```
$ sudo udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=block
```

Then finally check with if permissions were correctly set using:

```
$ ls -lL vg_usbraid-vm_webserver
brw-rw---- 1 root groupid  252,   8 Oct 26 09:26 vg_usbraid-vm_webserver
                  ^^^^^^^
```

And return the logging lever to the default setting:

```
$ sudo udevadm control --log-priority=err
```

Comment: More details can be found at http://wirespeed.xs4all.nl/mediawiki/index.php/Figuring_out_udev_rules but the article is not for the faint hearted ;o)